# How to embed your Jinja2 url_for in the style attribute while using flask?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, flask, jinja2

i am new to web development using python and flask. i am working on a sample project but unable to troubleshoot the error shown in the picture.

[image: the screen shot of my vscode screen]

the error is coming  in the style

```
 <header class="masthead" style= "background-image: url({{ url_for('static', filename='img/home-bg.jpg') }});">
            <div class="container position-relative px-4 px-lg-5">
                <div class="row gx-4 gx-lg-5 justify-content-center">
                    <div class="col-md-10 col-lg-8 col-xl-7">
                        <div class="site-heading">
                            <h1>Clean Blog</h1>
                            <span class="subheading">A Blog Theme by Start Bootstrap</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
```

Comment: find a Syntax Hightlight extension that knows Jinja2 syntax

Comment: You are missing one folder. Try changing `filename='img/home-bg.jpg'` to `filename='assets/img/home-bg.jpg'`. While this should show the desired picture, as rioV8 has pointed out, you will need some extension to accept jinja code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the style to img:

```
<header class="masthead" img="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/home-bg.jpg') }}">
<div class="container position-relative px-4 px-lg-5">
    <div class="row gx-4 gx-lg-5 justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-lg-8 col-xl-7">
            <div class="site-heading">
                <h1>Clean Blog</h1>
                <span class="subheading">A Blog Theme by Start Bootstrap</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When the content you transmit is a picture, I think it is more appropriate to use `img` tag.

Comment: thank you for the response ,I made the changes, but still I am unable get my required image where could be the possible error